# Find number of Each Day Type Left in Month (Excel)

Tags: excel

Trying to find the number of weekdays LEFT in the month: e.g. 2 Mondays, 2 Tuesdays, etc in excel.  Anyone know how I can go about doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of Excel are you using? If you have Excel 2010 you can customise `NETWORKDAYS.INTL` function to count any single day, e.g. to count `Mondays` from today until the end of the month (including today) you can use this formula

`=NETWORKDAYS.INTL(TODAY(),EOMONTH(TODAY(),0),"0111111")`

For Tuesdays use `"1011111"` for Wednesdays `"1101111"`, etc.

There are specific codes for common "weekends", e.g. 11 for Sunday weekends, but, in fact, you can use any combination of days by using a string as shown - zeroes denote days to be counted, 1s are days to be ignored - the string starts with Monday and ends with Sunday

Comment: where are you getting those binary-type numbers for day type?  All I have are whole number e.g. "12 for Monday only"