# Simple count date with month by month

Tags: excel, formula

I want to ask a formula that can automatically create the number of days from a date line. Then can be categorized based on the number of days in a month. I created a sample table like in the picture. And date data beside it. anyone can help??

[image: data sample]

Comment: You want to count Mondays, Tuesdays... in month, right?

Comment: Yes. Then can automatically fill in question marks in the table ..

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28681552/find-number-of-each-day-type-left-in-month-excel) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40077783/excel-calculate-remaining-mondays-in-each-month) questions can help you.

Comment: Of the two information
Nothing can add up if i write the formula in 1 column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the formula to count Mondays:

```
=NETWORKDAYS.INTL(DATE(2017,MONTH(1&T8),1),EOMONTH(DATE(2017,MONTH(1&T8),1),0),"0111111")
```

For Tuesdays change last param to  `"1011111"` and so on. I guess "July" in your table is in `T8`. If not, change both `T8` to the cell where "July" is. After filling first row, you can drag or copy it to the remaining rows.

There is a way to take days' names from your table instead of typing `"0111111"`, but it will make formula look much more complicated.